# Java Is there any way to initialize a generic array that's type safe?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code

```
public class Container<T> {
    private T element;
    private T[] tarray;

    public T getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(T element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public void add(T element) {
        tarray[0] = element;
    }

    public void CreateArray(int size) {
        //Can this be cleaned up better?
        tarray = (T[]) new Object[size];
    }

    public T get() {
        return tarray[0];
    }

    public Container(T someElement) {
        this.element = someElement;
    }

    public Container() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container<String> myContaier1 = new Container<String>();
        myContaier1.setElement("Hello");
        myContaier1.CreateArray(1);
        myContaier1.add("GoodBye");
        System.out.println(myContaier1.get());
    }
}
```

**Is there no way to initialize a type safe generic array?**

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation

Comment: It's effectively Object[] (just as well all standard containers like ArrayList), so threat it like one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way unless you provide a reified `T` in the form of an actual `Class<T>` object that represents a specific value of `T`. This is because the array type **is** reified, whereas the Generic type isn't.

Comment: Interestig word "reified". What does that mean? Is this a special Generics vocabulary?

Comment: @AlexWien It's a general term that also applies to the discussion about Generics. It means the runtime can observe it, as opposed to only the compiler. It means you can refer to it, pass it as an argument, have a method return it, store it in a variable, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

First of all, the actual type of your array will always be `Object[]`. You cast it to `T[]`, but this works only because `T[]` erases to `Object[]`. If your class definition said, for example, `<T extends Number>`, then `(T[])new Object[]` would fail with a `ClassCastException`.

You could get around this by passing `Class<T>` to the constructor of your collection and keeping it in a field:

```
private Class<T> componentClass;
...
tarray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(componentClass, size);
```

Now the actual in-memory type of `tarray` is `T[]`, but you still get an unchecked cast error. Even though you have the component class, as far as I know there is no equivalent of `Class.cast()` for doing a checked cast of an array instance.

Comment: "If your class definition said, for example, <T extends Number>, then (T[])new Object[] would fail with a ClassCastException." Right, but then in that case, it would be `(T[])new Number[]`. Basically, whatever T[] gets erased to.

Answer (score -1):

You can do `private T[] tarray;`, But you cannot assign it to `(T[]) new Object[size];`. How can an array of Object be same an array of any other class.
`T` is not even  there after compilation. 
It is called type erasure. E.g if you do

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

It becomes `List persons = new ArrayList()` after compilation.

Comment: what do you mean "cannot assign". What do you think will happen if you assign `(T[]) new Object[size];` to `tarray`?

Answer (score -1):

It is similar to ask "Is there a way to initialize a generic object: `new T()`?"

Of course it is impossible, as the compiler does not know what the type is of it.

Array is the same, its type relies on its elements. If the type of its elements is unknown, the type of itself is unknown.

Those classes which can take generic types like `List`, `Set`, `Map`, etc. are different. They have their own classes as types and they are dynamic, so you can initialize one like `new ArrayList<T>()`.

---

You can try on this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int[] i = new int[3];
        short[] s = new short[4];
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println(i.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(s.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(args.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(a.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

You will see the types of elements are already combined with the arrays, while not combined with ArrayList.

Answer (score -1):

There are way to do this on the JVM, but to do something like this in Java would require writing a lot of boiler plate code.  In Scala, you can use Manifests to get around type erasure, and can instantiate generic arrays without casting.

An example:

```scala
class Container[T : Manifest]() { 
  def createArray(size:Int) = Array.ofDim[T](size) 
}

scala> val f = new Container[String]
f: Container[String] = Container@12f3aa66

scala> f.createArray(5)
res7: Array[String] = Array(null, null, null, null, null)
```

Scala code compiles to the same bytecode class files as Java (implying that this should be possible in Java if you jumped through enough hoops and maybe wrote your own manifests).  Scala classes can be imported into Java projects... though I'm not sure how hard it is to instantiate a class like this from Java.

If you often find yourself wanting to be able to handle more complicated type situations, have a look at Scala, you might like it.